# How to convert a template string in JSON in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, template-strings

I have this code in my ty file:

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm){
console.log('Executado')
let dados = `
  name: ${form.value.name},
  email: ${form.value.email},
  specialty: ${form.value.specialty},
  password:${form.value.password}

  `;
  this.http.post(`${ this.apiURL }/auth/register_lawyer`, dados)
        .subscribe(
          resultado => {
            console.log(resultado)
          },
          erro => {
            if(erro.status == 400) {
              console.log(erro);
            }
          }
        )
}
```

How can I convert the dados I receive in the form into JSON file? something like:

```
   dados ={
"name":"Andrew",
"email":"teste@hotmail.com",
"specialty":"developer,
"password":"1234"

}
```

I want to pass the dados in JSON form via Post to my API. But  I searched and found nothing. I tried to use JSON.stringfy but not worked.

Comment: There's a bug in your code: ask yourself what happens if someone submits a value for `name` that contains a newline character or a double-quote or a comma?

Comment: JSON.stringify should be enough, what is the returned error ?

Comment: @AdMer `JSON.stringify` won't work because `dados` is already a string. (See the backticks), It isn't an `object`.

Comment: @Dai You're right didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

Your `dados` string is not valid JSON because it doesn't follow JSON formatting rules (e.g. all keys must be in double-quotes, all strings must be delimited, etc). Don't use template-strings to create JSON data because you'll need to handle things like escaping strings and things like that.

Change your code to create a DTO `object` first, then if you still want your `dados` template-string then create that separately. To avoid repetition you could use a function to generate the string by enumerating the properties of the DTO.

```
const dto = {
    name     : form.value.name,
    email    : form.value.email,
    specialty: form.value.specialty,
    password : form.value.password
};

const url = `${ this.apiURL }/auth/register_lawyer`;
this.http.post( url, dto )    // <-- Passing a JavaScript `object` will automatically be converted to JSON by Angular: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request
    .subscribe( resultado => {
        console.log(resultado)
        },
        erro => {
            if(erro.status == 400) {
                console.log(erro);
            }
        }
    );

const dados = `
    name: ${dto.name},
    email: ${dto.email},
    specialty: ${dto.specialty},
    password:${dto.password}
`;
```

If you want to create lots of those `dados` strings (**which are not JSON**), perhaps for logging purposes? (honestly, no idea), do this:

```
function createTextThatIsNotJson( obj ) {

    let text = "";
    for( const key in obj ) {
        if( text.length > 0 ) text += ",\r\n";
        text += "    " + key + ": " + obj[key];
    }
    return text;
}

const dados = createTextThatIsNotJson( dto );
```

Comment: WOOOOORKEEDDDD THANKSSS